# PhpStorm docblock autocomplete for @author tag

Tags: phpstorm

I'd like to have autocomplete @author tag for **functions** I'm writing. For eg. If I write `@author` and press space it should autocomplete my name and email as in the form of typical @author tag. Is there a option for that in PhpStorm or other way to achieve it?

Comment: There is no such functionality just for `@author` tag. You can override any File or Code template in settings so they will use correct `@author Your Name` content right away (e.g. when creating brand new file or PHPDoc for certain elements). You may also use Copyright plugin for managing copyright profiles (will add/update your file-level copyright comment; works with files only).

Comment: Also you can use live template. For example write @a hit tab and get tag and author name immediately ;)